# Break after so many divs

Tags: php, jquery

I have 4 hard coded divs. After the third div I would like to break or put the 4th div on a new line. How do I do this and can I do this php or do I have to use javascript/jQuery? The divs are wrapped in a label tag btw.  ***I forgot to mention that the labels are dynamically turned on. So not all labels are viewed at once.***

```
<label class="1">
    <div id="div1">Stuff 1</div>
</label>
<label class="2">
    <div id="div2">Stuff 2</div>
</label>
<label class="3">
    <div id="div3">Stuff 3</div>
</label>
<label class="4">
    <div id="div4">Stuff 4</div>
</label>
```

Comment: `<br />` is the easiest solution

Comment: If I'm not mistaken they should all be on separate lines anyway. Have you put a `display:inline` style in there somewhere?

Comment: I updated the question. But yes I have additional css that make them inline

Comment: Please post relevant javascript code to show how the labels are shown dynamically.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`nth-child`](http://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/):

```
$('label:nth-child(4n)').after("<br/>");​
```

Comment: I didn't know you could have multipliers in `nth-child(n)` - very cool.

Comment: @paislee - Is there a way to add an additional check to see if the label is visible first and then do this in this script?

Comment: @Joe check out jQuery's `.filter(':visible')`

Answer (score 1):

You can loop through the labels with jquery's [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) method and add `<br/>` if the current index is divisible by 3.

```
$("label").each(function(i){
   if (i%3 == 0)
   {
       $(this).after("<br/>");
   }
});
```

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan nope, jQuery sets `i` when calling the anonymous callback.

Comment: yes yes sorry i'm mobile and the (i) inside braces was eaten by my res. +1

Comment: Thanks @jrummell This is another interesting way of doing it